# Emberjs-1.0 component and compute property in controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I am passing a controller into an **[emberjs component](http://jsfiddle.net/Xajsr/)**. The controller has a computed property called **dateArray** that holds an an array of dates. After clicking on a **#linkTo** that points to appointment template, I can go into the console and do:

```
    b = App.__container__.lookup("controller:appointment")
    c = b.get('dateArray')
    and it returns [Array[2]]
```

However, when I pass that controller into an **emberjs component** with

```
      {{date-picker datePickerController=controller}}
```

Inside the component, I can get the correct instance of the controller , using the code below

```
 datePicker = _this.get('datePickerController');
 console.log(datePicker), shows the dateArray with its content.
```

but the array displays as empty, when i fectch it based on the above instance using the code below.

```
  controllerContent = datePicker.get('dateArray');
```

However if I add the **dateArray** in a handlebars expressions in the appointments template, it renders its content:

```
  {{dateArray}}
```

So why its **dateArray** empty inside **emberjs component** when controller instance  the **emberjs component** has the **dateArray**

The controller:

```
App.AppointmentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   needs: [ 'timeSlot'],
   timeSlotController: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.timeSlot'),
   dateArray: function(){
     _this = this;  

     fetchDates = [ ];

    var aa = _this.get('content'); 

    var yy = aa.get('timeSlots')

    yy.then(function(hh){
        nn = hh.map(function(item){ return moment.utc(item.get('startTime')).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); });

     pp =  fetchDates.pushObjects([nn]);

     return nn;
    });  

    return fetchDates;
  }.property('content.@each.timeSlots')


});
```

The emberjs component:

```
App.DatePickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   datePickerController: null,

   didInsertElement: function() {
     this._super();
     _this = this;
     var datePicker;

     datePicker = _this.get('datePickerController');
    //console.log(datePicker);

     var controllerContent = datePicker.get('dateArray');    

    //returns nil
     alert(controllerContent); 

    });// closes didInsertElement

  }

 });
```

Comment: If you add a breakpointinto the dateArray computed property, does it get hit when you call get again on this line: var controllerContent = datePicker.get('dateArray');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `dateArray` property is async, because you are using `yy.then`.

This is what happens:

You call `datePicker.get('dateArray')` this trigger `yy.then` but it doesn't resolve immediatelly, you return `fetchDates` as empty array. When `yy.then` load, it will populate the array with `fetchDates.pushObjects([nn])` so this update the template.

I recommend you to observe changes in the array to perform what you want:

```
App.DatePickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  datePickerController: null,
  dateArrayChanged: function() {
    var dateArray = this.get('datePickerController.dateArray');
    // now date array have elements
  }.observes('datePickerController.dateArray.[]')
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Márcio for your helpful explanation. You are correct because I can now get the array from inside **dateArrayChanged**. Do you have any suggestions on why the **dat function** that is updated from inside **dateArrayChanged** to contain the dates is returning **undefined**. Both of them are defined inside the **DatePickerComponent** in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xajsr/2/)**

Comment: In the dat function use b =  this.get('datePickerController.dateArray'); Don't forget to ever use get and set to read/update properties of ember objects

Comment: @Edu, thanks for that suggestion. I still have one problem, calling the **dat** function in the **didInsertElement** with something like **alert(this.dat());**, still returns undefined, event though inside the **dat function or method**, I have **alert( this.get('datePickerController.dateArray'))** which returns the right thing. Here is an **[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xajsr/3/)**. In the datePicker-component, the **dat function** is defined after the **didInsertElement**. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Ember a controller is a weird thing to pass around, it's just a decorator over a model, if your model changes underneath your controller your controller could be completely different (maybe that's your intention).  You might try passing in the dateArray into the component.

Comment: this works by displaying on the componenet's template, however, i am using this **a.forEach(function(item) { return item;});** to try to loop over it in the componenet itself and it is still undefined. Any suggestions